# Born a X, reaching adulthood no longer a X, but dead, X

Tags: riddle, word

> Born a X, reaching adulthood no longer a X, but dead, X.

What is X?

Clue 1

> Although alluded to by the use of "adulthood" X was regarded as a living being.

Comment: Can we take into consideration the article 'a' or can the word have the article 'an' as well?

Comment: only the article 'a' renders a syntactically "sound" statement

Comment: Is it rot13(pngrecvyyne)? not sure of the last part though

Comment: @Daniil That isn't the intended answer, but nice try. I'm not sure it would satisfy the riddle as an alternative answer however as I wouldn't consider a dead butterfly to be a caterpiller, although they may have identical genomes.

Comment: Would rot13(teho) be acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> **Mute**, as in "lacking the power of speech"

Explanation

> So when born, babies lack the power of speech but upon reaching adulthood would no longer be rendered mute. However, dead people lack the power of speech. This word also works well in the sentence structure as it is a noun and an adjective.
>  Born a **mute**, reaching adulthood no longer a **mute**, but dead, **mute**.

Comment: I suppose it could also be rot13(oyvaq)

Comment: The hint does say that X is a living being though.

Answer (score 5):

I barely see a real corny answer as

> grain, the seed of a crop which when harvested is grain.

Answer (score 0):

Could X be a

> Caterpillar, which later becomes a butterfly.